# Sha512 Hashing with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, hash, xamarin, sha512

Please consider the following code:

```
   SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
   byte[] data = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password"));

   StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
   {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
   }

   string stringyHash = sBuilder.ToString();
```

I am using the above method to generate a SHA512 hashed password for an android device using Xamarin. However when I output `stringyHash` I am given a completely different hash to what I expect when using an online hashing service such as:
http://www.convertstring.com/Hash/SHA512

The difference for hashing the string "password" between the online tool and my Xamarin implementation is as follows:

Xamarin:

> cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e

Online tool:

> B109F3BBBC244EB82441917ED06D618B9008DD09B3BEFD1B5E07394C706A8BB980B1D7785E5976EC049B46DF5F1326AF5A2EA6D103FD07C95385FFAB0CACBC86

I am relatively new to Xamarin and have little experience with hashing as a concept, so if someone can explain why the two are different, and how to adjust my code to make sure I am producing a *correct* hash, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The *b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e07394c706a8bb980b1d7785e5976ec049b46df5f1326af5a2ea6d103fd07c95385ffab0cacbc86* is the one generated by .NET on Visual Studio... So if there is a problem, it is in Xamarin.

Comment: I would suggest you, to not hash in your end device (performance). Rather do it in your backend (webservice or so). Also you could try using the SHA512 class in .NET. See here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512(v=vs.110).aspx=

Comment: mono may have a different implementation of SHA512, if you want something consistent use Bouncy Castle, http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Comment: This is for password checking, rather than creation, so the hashed PW is already stored in the back-end, but i'd rather not send a plain text password over potentially unsecured networks.

Comment: This is how it is mostly done. You can send the password plaintext over a SSL secured channel and check it in your backend.

Comment: @Gusman No, there is a definite "standard" on what a SHA512 is. And Mono implements it: https://ideone.com/yoHjua

Comment: http://ideone.com/shQzNZ

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110948/password-hashing-on-frontend-or-backend)

Comment: Well, you're right guys, I just created a xam app on android and yields the correct result, the user posted a code which is not the same as he is using.

Comment: Side note: wrap `SHA512` into using, since it's `IDisposable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e

Is the SHA-512 hash of a zero length string:

```
byte[] data = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""));
```

So there is an issue with whatever you feed into your Xamarin method.

Comment: You are absolutely right, for some reason it's receiving an empty string. that's one mystery solved, thanks.